# Django DateTimeField and User Input fields not added

Tags: python, django, forms, datetime, form-fields

I am beginner to python Django. I'm working on practice project. I got stuck while adding a product.
Its adds all the fields except two fields
 i. DateTimeField
ii. User (who add the product)

The error which i'm facing is:

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: null value in column "pub_date" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (3, Piano, Ball Pens(set of 3), 15, 30, 10, images/ballpens_QdhwoOa.jpg, null, null).
```

**models.py**

```
class Product(models.Model):
    companyName    = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    pro_name       = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    Purchase_Price = models.IntegerField()
    Sale_Price     = models.IntegerField()
    Quantity       = models.IntegerField()
    Picture        = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/')
    saler          = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    pub_date       = models.DateTimeField()

    def pub_date_pretty(self):
        return self.pub_date.strftime('%b %e %Y')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.pro_name
```

**views.py**

```
class AddProduct(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'stock/addproduct.html'

    def get(self, request):
        form = AddProductForm()
        args = {'form':form}
        return render(request, self.template_name, args)

    def post(self, request):
        form = AddProductForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            productadded = form.save()
            productadded.saler =  request.user
            productadded.pub_date = timezone.datetime.now()
            productadded.save()
            return redirect('stock')
        else:
            args = {'form': form}
            return render(request, self.template_name, args)
```

In **views.py**, I am saving a user and date and time as you see in above
**forms.py**

```
class AddProductForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ('companyName', 'pro_name', 'Purchase_Price', 'Sale_Price', 'Quantity', 'Picture' )

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(AddProductForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['companyName'].label    = 'Company Name'
        self.fields['pro_name'].label       = 'Product Name'
        self.fields['Purchase_Price'].label = 'Purchase Price'
        self.fields['Sale_Price'].label     = 'Sale Price'
```

Your help will be appreciated.
Thank You

Comment: `productadded = form.save(commit=False)` will return the unsaved instance. It should work then.

Comment: Thank you. Now, its working. Kindly briefly explain what "commit=False" that is doing here .

Comment: `form.save()` returns a model instance. The `commit` argument controls whether that instance is already saved to the db or not. In your case, you cannot save it directly because your form excludes a non-nullable default-less model field, which you correctly set after that. Hope that helps. Btw, yo can handle that in the field definition: `pub_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do a small correction

```
       if form.is_valid():
            productadded = form.save(commit=False)
            productadded.saler =  request.user
            productadded.pub_date = timezone.datetime.now()
            productadded.save()
            return redirect('stock')
```

Comment: Thank you. Now, its working. Kindly briefly explain what "commit=False" that is doing  here

Comment: commit=False will not push the changes in the database, but it will create the all structure needed for it, but you will have to trigger the regular save later on with manually add the required fields, otherwise your form will not be saved in the database